# Maintaining an audit trail on specific entitities (tables) in SQL Server, using triggers (and a stored proc)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I want to maintain an audit trail for some tables in a SQL Server database. For these tables, I want to record all CRUD activities on the entity (object) stored in the table. This is the table schema I have come up with so far. For updates to an entity, please note that I am storing detailed data showing the fields that were changed, in a sub (related) table. To be able to store different values in the same column, I am storing the text representations of the data type of the field.

I would want some feedback on:

1. The table design (can it be improved?, are there any gotchas to be aware of with this design)?
2. I would like to write a trigger (per monitored table), so that I can provide an audit trail for CRUD operations on the monitored entity. I am new to triggers, so an example of how I can use a trigger to record CRUD operations on entity Foo would be very useful. Being the lazy bugger that I am, I want to keep the SQL `DRY`, so I would like all of the triggers to call a common stored proc that takes the (what,why, when) as parameters.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo  (
        id      INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        field_1     REAL,
        field_2     VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
        field_3     BIT,
        field_4     IMAGE
        field_5     VARCHAR(256), -- Path to an image file
        field_6         DATE,
        field_7     TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        field_8     INTEGER REFERENCES Personnel(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION
    );


-- store CRUD actions info (who, what, when, why) on specific tables
CREATE TABLE GenericRecordArchive (
            id          INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            personnel_id        INTEGER REFERENCES Personnel(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,     -- who
            monitored_object_id INTEGER REFERENCES MonitoredObject(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,   -- what ...
            crud_type_id        INTEGER REFERENCES CrudType(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION, 
                    reason          TEXT NOT NULL,                                  -- why
            created_at      TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                    -- when
        );



-- Detailed archive info for updates, stored changed fields (for updates only)
CREATE TABLE GenericRecordArchiveInfo (
            id          INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            archive_record_id   INTEGER REFERENCES GenericRecordArchive(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,
            field_name      VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            old_value       TEXT,
            new_value       TEXT,
            created_at      TIMESTAMP
        );
```

Notes:

- For the sake of simplicity, I have not included indices etc in the schema above
- Although I am working on SQL Server, I may want to port this to some other database in the future, so wherever possible, I would like the SQL to be as db agnostic as possible (unless there are huge efficiency gains, parsimony of code etc. by keeping the SQL code SQL Server centric).

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. **Avoid using these data types** in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Depending on your version of SQL Server, why reinvent the wheel? Can't you just use the built-in [Change Data Capture (CDC)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) feature? It's already there, it's already built, it's tested by thousands of users......

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks for the heads up. I am quite new to SQL Server, so wasn't aware of the data type changes. Regarding using CDC, in my second note, I pointed out that I will try to make the solution as generic as possible (i.e. database agnostic - as much as possible), to ease porting to other databases. Still it will be interesting to see how CDC has been implemented - so thanks for the link

Comment: Hmm, something happened to the formatting after my edit - can't seem to get the formatting of the code right - any help?

Comment: If you include your code snippets in a numbered or unnumbered list, you need to indent it by **8 spaces** (not just 4) - or just add a line like I did (`Code:`) to "end" the numbered list